# VBA: pastespecial always pastes as image in destination excel sheet. Tried all available arguments but everything pastes image instead of text

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I am running following code from UFT tool and it always copies and paste the values as image instead of text.

'Code:

```
 Set WB2 = GetObject(FileName2) 'Get the Destination Excel File Handle which is already opened
WB2.Worksheets("WebADI").Unprotect
Set Myexcel=createobject("excel.application")     'Create Excel Object
Myexcel.Visible=True
Set WB1=Myexcel.Workbooks.Open(FileName)    'Open the Source Excel File
Myexcel.Visible=True    
WB1.Activate()
WB1.Worksheets("CHPGEFABRFQ").Range("$B$5:$AE$11").Copy
WB2.Activate()
Myexcel.Visible=True    
WB2.Worksheets("WebADI").Range("$C$5").PasteSpecial
```

Tried all possible pastespecial options like shown below none works. Can someone help?

```
PasteSpecial Paste=xlPasteValues
PasteSpecial Paste=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
PasteSpecial Paste=xlPasteFormulas
PasteSpecial Paste=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
PasteSpecial Paste=xlPasteAllExceptBorders
PasteSpecial Paste=xlPasteColumnWidths
```

Answer (score 2):

I tested it just now and I think `.Copy` doesn't handle two separate excel applications well. But I had no issues copying the values into an array and then copying the array into a separate application/workbook.

Here is how you would copy/paste as an array of values instead of using the clipboard.

```vb
Dim ValArray As Variant

Set WB2 = GetObject(FileName2) 'Get the Destination Excel File Handle which is already opened
WB2.Worksheets("WebADI").Unprotect
Set Myexcel = CreateObject("excel.application")   'Create Excel Object
Myexcel.Visible = True
Set WB1 = Myexcel.Workbooks.Open(Filename)  'Open the Source Excel File

ValArray = WB1.Worksheets("CHPGEFABRFQ").Range("$B$5:$AE$11").Value

WB2.Worksheets("WebADI").Range("$C$5").Resize(UBound(ValArray), UBound(ValArray, 2)).Value = ValArray
```

Comment: Hi Toddleson, Thank you for the reply. I am able to paste this as text now, but the "B5" cell value is displayed as "WB2.Worksheets("WebADI").Range("$C$5").Resize(UBound(ValArray), UBound(ValArray, 2)).Value = ValArray" and the rest is copied as text properly.

Comment: That has never happened to me before and I have no idea why your VBA would output an array like that. If you pause the script before `End Sub` and inspect ValArray in the Watch window, does the first element contain the correct value or the formula?

Comment: I found the issue, I haven't commented "WB2.Worksheets("WebADI").Range("$C$5").PasteSpecial " line after copying values using array and it pasted the formula in B5 cell.  
Thanks Toddleson for your help. Your code worked perfectly.